# How to specify a template for a path like http://example.com/something?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, templates

I created a custom post type ('explore') that we use in the site.  The pages for this section live at http://example.com/explore/page-name

These pages work just fine, but if a user were to back out of that url and go to http://example.com/explore they are getting the generic `index.php` page that is NOT what we want people to see here.

Considering this url does NOT point to any content, how can I specify which template to use?  I can echo out the `get_post_type()` and it shows `'explore'` as the post type, but I'm seeing that from the `index.php` template.

I tried adding a `page-explore.php` but that didn't work.  There doesn't seem to be a `index-[custom-type].php`

Thanks.

Comment: if `/explore` is showing a post archive of that post type then can you not use the standard post archive template from the template hierarchy diagram as outlined in the official handbook docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the "custom post type archive template". That's `archive-{post_type}.php`, or in your case `archive-explore.php`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/

Comment: Works, perfectly.  Thanks!